# add $ and round 2 decimal places SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, format

I am looking to format an ouput which is created by a sub-query, this sub-query produces a calculated field which i would like to format as $XX.XX.

Sub query:

```
(select avg(retail) from cars 
where brand = 'FORD' or brand = 'TOYOTA') as AVG_BRAND_PRICE_01
```

I basically just want to add a $ sign and round the output to two decimal places.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

I am using isql plus oracle 11g

Comment: `set numformat` as you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
'$' || Cast((select avg(retail) from cars 
where brand = 'FORD' or brand = 'TOYOTA') as decimal(4,2)) as AVG_BRAND_PRICE_01
```

If you want more than $XX.XX e.g $XXXXXXX.XX then you will need to set the decimal higher e.g. decimal(9,2)

Example SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f684/2/0

Comment: @ChristianBarron You just need to set the display the way you want. All that concatenation and CAST is unnecessary. The data type of the output is changed from number to character, that is not what OP wants.

Comment: @ChristianBarron I am afraid you took in wrong way. This is a community and we discuss things. I commented to both you and OP. And regarding OP accepting the answer, he might not even be aware of the data type change. Don't you think it is good if we tell him.

Comment: Of course he should know the options but you have listed the options to him by providing your alternative answer. If you want clarification on what the op wants then you should comment on his question not my answer

Comment: Christians answer provided the result I required for this part of the query which is a single sub-query, the ended purpose was to display the data as $XX.XX. As the query that Christina provide has done so, I am open to other options but I found that one above the easiest for my problem :D

Comment: I would be more than happy if that is what you want.

Comment: @ITworldR I would be more than happy if that is what you want. But, as I said, If all you need is to control the display format on **`SQL*Plus`**, then it is better to use the **`SQL*Plus`** commands to control the display format rather than applying functions at SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

> I basically just want to add a $ sign and round the output to two decimal places.
>
> I am using isql plus oracle 11g

It is a simple **display** setting. You need to set the **NUMFORMAT** properly.

If all you need is to **control the display format** on `SQL*Plus`, then it is better to use the `SQL*Plus` commands to control the display format rather than applying functions at SQL level.

In **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> SELECT AVG(sal) FROM emp;

  AVG(SAL)
----------
2073.21429

SQL> set numformat $9999D99
SQL> SELECT AVG(sal) FROM emp;

 AVG(SAL)
---------
 $2073.21

SQL>
```

If you explicitly ROUND the value to two decimal places, then use the **ROUND** function:

```
SQL> set numformat $9999D99
SQL> SELECT ROUND(AVG(sal),2) FROM emp;

ROUND(AVG(SAL),2)
-----------------
         $2073.21

SQL>
```

If you want a specific format for a particular column, then you could use the **COLUMN FORMAT** command, which would override the `SET NUMFORMAT` property for that column.

For example,

```
SQL> set numformat $99999.99
SQL> column comm format 99999.99
SQL> select sal, comm from emp where rownum <=5;

        SAL      COMM
----------- ---------
    $800.00
   $1600.00    300.00
   $1250.00    500.00
   $2975.00
   $1250.00   1400.00
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it assumes all numeric values returned in the select are to be in this format. The op asked that his subquery be returned in this format, you don't know what else he is selecting

Comment: @ChristianBarron When OP's subquery is returning the average value of retail, then of course it is a number and not character. And since it is a subquery, it's output would be used in the outer query one level up, and the desired data type would be number and not string. And, this is a simple requirement of displaying a number in a desired format in SQL*Plus, which has nothing to do with what you suggested to cast it and concatenate with a string to ultimately convert it into a string.

Comment: I'm not saying mine is the best answer, I'm just saying that if he has other numerics being selected which he does not want in this format then your solution will change all his numerics to this format. Am I right?

Comment: @ChristianBarron It is quite obvious that he just wants for this query returning only single column. Else, why would a format matter if the expected value is derived from a sub-query?

Comment: Why is it obvious? If he wanted to return only 1 column he would have just used a select and not a subquery. You're just making the assumption there is only one column being returned here

Comment: @ChristianBarron SQL*Plus has many format options. It is not that if you set the numformat, then you cannot alter the format of other numeric columns. `COLUMN FORMAT` command would be used for other columns. See my updated answer. All I am saying is, when you need to format the display in `SQL*Plus`, why would I apply functions on the column at SQL level? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: That's fine, all you needed to do was change it to column format. All I was saying is Numformat would have affected other selected columns.

Comment: @ChristianBarron column format will always override numformat. That's how it is designed, that's how we use it while creating reports on **SQL*Plus**. Anyway, I hope you got it what I was pointing to. And no hard feelings, just a regular technical discussion :-)

Comment: Certainly no hard feelings. Just a technical debate and we're obviously passionate that the op gets what he wants ha! :)